# CUDA kernel for cumulative product of complex numbers

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have a for-loop written in C code that I would like to convert to a CUDA kernel. The code is shown below:

```
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

int main(){
  cuComplex *h_a, h_b;
  unsigned int N = 7;
  h_a = (cuComplex*)malloc(N*sizeof(cuComplex));
  h_b.x = h_b.y = 1.0f;

  // initialize h_a
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    h_a[i].x = (float)(i + 1);
    h_a[i].y = 1.0f;
  }

  // *************************************
  // Convert following to CUDA kernel ?
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    h_b.x *= h_a[i].x;
    h_b.y *= h_a[i].y;
  }
  // *************************************

  return 0;
}
```

I would like to keep the values of h_a array unmodified within the CUDA kernel and just modify the h_b value. I suspect some kind of reduction within the CUDA kernel is needed but am unsure.

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The architecture is Nvidia CUDA 10.x". There is no such thing. And your GPU code doesn't do the same thing as your CPU implementation. Correctness before performance.

Comment: @talonmies, sorry about the mix-up. You are right, my original code was incorrect. I made changes to what I originally posted such that I would just like to know how to go about defining a CUDA kernel that will execute the for-loop currently defined in C code.

Comment: For an array size of `N=7` I would expect the device to always perform worse than the host for what's basically "set the value of 2 array elements". Have a look at one of the many open tutorials or online books on how to write cuda kernels, such as "CUDA by example" to learn how to write basic kernels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a form a reduction, and the simplest way to calculate this on the GPU with (near) optimal performance would be to use the thrust library:

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/complex.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef thrust::complex<float> cfloat;
struct mult
{
    __host__ __device__
    cfloat operator()(const cfloat& x, const cfloat& y) const
    { 
        return cfloat(x.real() * y.real(), x.imag() * y.imag());
    }
};

int main()
{
    const int N = 7;

    thrust::host_vector<cfloat> A(N);

    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) 
        A[i] = cfloat(float(i + 1.0f), 1.0f);  

    thrust::device_vector<cfloat> A_d(N);
    thrust::copy(A.begin(), A.end(), A_d.begin());

    cfloat init(1.0f, 1.0f);
    auto result = thrust::reduce(A_d.begin(), A_d.end(), init, mult());

    std::cout << "Result = " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which compiles and runs as follows (CUDA 9.1):

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 -o product product.cu 
$ ./product 
Result = (5040,1)
```

If you want to write your own kernel, reduction is an extremely well described operation in CUDA, and it is trivial to adapt an existing implementation to perform the product you want rather than the more typical summation  or min/max operations you will find in the CUDA samples or with the search engine of your choice.

Comment: Thank you @talonmies. I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to @talonmies for the great answer, Thrust makes things much easier.

I did run across CUDA CUB for a similar solution, which may help someone out if (for whatever reason), they can't use Thrust.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuComplex.h>
#include "cub/cub.cuh"  // assumes CUB is in current directory

struct ComplexProd{
  __device__ __forceinline__
  cuComplex operator()(cuComplex &a, cuComplex &b){
    a.x = a.x * b.x;
    a.y = a.y * b.y;
    return a;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  const int N = 64;
  cuComplex *d_a, *d_b;
  cuComplex *h_a, h_b;
  cuComplex chk;

  h_a = (cuComplex*)malloc(N*sizeof(cuComplex));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, N*sizeof(cuComplex));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b, sizeof(cuComplex));

  // initialize
  h_b.x = h_b.y = 1.0f;

  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    h_a[i].x = (float)(i + 1);
    h_a[i].y = 1.0f;
  }

  // compute on HOST
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
    h_b.x *= h_a[i].x;
    h_b.y *= h_a[i].y;
  }

  // copy to DEVICE
  cudaMemcpy(d_a, h_a, N*sizeof(cuComplex),   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

  ComplexProd prod;
  cuComplex init;
  void *d_temp_storage = NULL;
  size_t temp_storage_bytes = 0;

  // set initial value - same as HOST 
  init.x = init.y = 1.0f;

  // determine temporary device storage requirements
  cub::DeviceReduce::Reduce(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_a, d_b, N, prod, init);
  cudaMalloc(&d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes);

  // run actual reduction via CUB
  cub::DeviceReduce::Reduce(d_temp_storage, temp_storage_bytes, d_a, d_b, N, prod, init);
  cudaFree(&d_temp_storage);

  // get result from GPU
  cudaMemcpy(&chk, d_b, sizeof(cuComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  // output results
  print("HOST: %0.4f, DEVICE: %0.4f\n", h_b.x, chk.x);

  // free memory
  free(h_a);
  cudaFree(d_a);
  cudaFree(d_b);

  return 0;
}
```